# Xamarin Forms: Object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageCell' cannot be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.View'

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Home-->
    <ImageCell ImageSource="Home.png" Text="Home" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Home.png is in the android, ios and UWP projects but I get the above error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageCell (and all *Cell controls) is intended for us in ListView and Tables.  In this case you should  use the regular Image control.

Comment: Image control doesn't have click. Just trying to create a basic button with a glyph on it and some text which is trivial in UWP and other flavors of XAML.

Comment: you can use a GestureRecognizer to add a Tapped event

Comment: This would require that the glyph have the text for the button in the image as well causing my deploy to be huge with every button.  Worse it appears that the button controls on all platforms don't have styling for mouseover so any device with a mouse hooked up will get horrible styling.  And XLabs is out of date and breaks a ton of things too.